# how to compute t-test step by step

Tags: excel, statistics

I am trying to compute the t-test using Excel, without the macro included in the software. 
Specifically, given a dataset, for example

```
var1
21
34
23
32
21
42
32
12
53
31
21 - from here
41
12
14
24 - to here
```

I am interesting in analysing the change in the last five rows (from `21` to `24`).
What I did is to compute the mean of the two samples of data, i.e. of the `set1` (from `21` to `31`) and of the `set2` (from `21` to `24`). 
Then, I compute the variance of these sets, using `var.S`.
Once I did it, I used the formula for unequal sample sizes, unequal variances to determine the degree of freedom. 
Now, what I should do is using the `t.dist` function in Excel to get the final result. However, I cannot understand the parameters to insert.

Could you please tell me what I should do and if it is ok what I have done until now?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Having `21` at the start of both sets of data led to some confusion about which points were being compared with which; a different example (or explicitly identifying both sets in the diagram, not just the second one) could avoid that ambiguity.
2. Note that if these are time series data, the assumption of independence will usually not be tenable.
3. You don't need a macro, Excel has a built in t-test function ([`T.TEST`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/T-TEST-function-D4E08EC3-C545-485F-962E-276F7CBED055)) that is capable of doing what you ask for.

   `T.TEST(array1,array2,tails,type)`

   `array1` and `array2` should be two non-overlapping sets of observations.

   `tails` should be 1 or 2 depending on whether you need a 1- or 2-tailed test. I presume you want two tailed. (If it's one-tailed, beware; it actually just reports half the two-tailed p-value, which is not correct if the sample means are in the opposite direction to the one hypothesized in the one-tailed alternative.)

   `type` is 1,2 or 3 depending on whether you want paired, independent with equal variance or independent with unequal variance. (It's possible to make the paired test option do a one-sample t-test as well)

   There's an explicit example of using this function at the link above.
4. With your approach you next need to compute the [t-statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes,_unequal_variances) before trying to use the `t.dist` function; that's the first argument.

Comment: For the assigned exercise I cannot use the built in t-test function.

Comment: Kind of important to explain the restriction. Also, I believe it's important to be explicit about this being an assignment. The formulas for the Welch t-test are on wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_unequal_sample_sizes,_unequal_variances). It's a simple matter to compute each component.